# Getting an exception-" The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

While executing the below code I am getting the exception:

> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

```
List<string> List_Items = new List<string>();
List_Items = Retail_Team_Id.Get_Retail_Team_Id(Incident_Path, List_Retail);
for (int i = 0; i < List_Items.Count(); i++)
{
   MySheet.Cells[(i+2), 40] = List_Items[i];//Here getting the exception
}
```

Comment: is your error in Retail_Team_Id.Get_Retail_Team_Id? what is it doing? where exactly do you get error?

Comment: What happens if you replace List_Items with a list of known strings - like {"a", "b", "c"} - do the cells populate?

Comment: Also, are you trying to talk to Excel from ASP.NET server-side? That isn't going to work very well. You need a library like SpreadsheetGear to manipulate spreadsheets server-side

Comment: No. Its at MySheet.Cells[(i+2), 40].

Comment: I am running in the local server only.

Comment: Is it anything to do with the ram?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution, because i m having similar issue.